# Extract a list using comma and quotation marks together

Tags: google-sheets

I got a list of text string on a column in a Google Spreadsheet and I would like to extract it separating the values with a comma and delimiting them with quotation marks, in this way: "...", "...", "...", "..."
Now I know how to comma separate the values, with this formula:

```
=arrayformula(concatenate(filter(a2:a;a2:a<>"")&", "))
```

but how to add quotation mark too?
thank you

---

EDIT:
Solution suggested by @pnuts:

```
=char(34)&join(""", """,A2:A4)&char(34)
```

Thank you!

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
=arrayformula(concatenate(filter(char (34)&a2:a&char (34);a2:a<>"")&", "))
```

Comment: @pnuts  I would use `REGEX` . Longer?  yes. Double the length?  No.  `=arrayformula(REGEXREPLACE(concatenate(filter(char (34)&A2:A&char (34),A2:A<>"")&", "), "(.*), $", "$1"))`

Comment: @pnuts A bit longer:`arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE(concatenate(filter(char (34)&A2:A&char (34),A2:A<>"")&", "),", ","",COUNTA(A2:A)))`